# Appending filtered range to sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

With this code I simply (Thanks to Slai) copy and paste a filtered range from one sheet to another. However I attempted to replicate this code by appending another filtered range to the HAA sheet but for some reason it selects row 11 and pastes the data.

```
Sub Run()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim x As Long
    Dim rf As Range, wsTo As Worksheet, wx As Range

    Set rf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table").UsedRange
    Set wsTo = Sheets("HAA")
    Set wx = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HAA").UsedRange

    x = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    rf.AutoFilter
    rf.AutoFilter 12, "associated"
    rf.Copy

    wsTo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    rf.AutoFilter
    rf.AutoFilter 12, "not found"
    rf.Offset(1, 0).Copy
```

I changed this (below) to select to see where it was pasting the data, originally had .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

```
    wsTo.Range("A1" & x).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What worksheet are you trying to get the last populated row (e.g. **x**) from? Why are you not offsetting to get the first available blank cell? e.g. `x = wsTo.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).OFFSET(1, 0).Row` It looks like it should be `wsTo.Range("A" & x).Select`.

Comment: would you add some examples of input and desired results?

Comment: @Jeeped x = wsTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With this, it pastes over the existing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paste after the last row, something like:

```
Dim rangeTo As Range
Set rangeTo = wsTo.UsedRange ' or = wsTo.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rangeTo = rangeTo.Offset(rangeTo.Rows.Count)(1) ' (1) is to get the first cell 
Application.Goto rangeTo ' optional if you want to see where the values will be pasted
rangeTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The problem in your code is that you get the last row before you paste and filter the data. Also, `Range(` usually refers to the currently active Sheet which might not always be the one you want, so it's better to specify the sheet before the Range:

```
 x = wsTo.Range("B" & wsTo.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Now I'm getting object required for the rangeTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteValue
but I thought this was already identified before this was executed.

Comment: @FonR did you forget to copy the data before paste?

Comment: Give me a moment to think about this.

Comment: I wish for you to be my mentor. I did not realize that the Dim & Set have to used when previous fuctions occurred. Also, one of the hardest things for me it getting the layering of the objects correct. Man, you are good. I know these are simple fuctions but you really know what you are doing. I don't want to take the code and just paste it, I want to learn from it. Thank you

Comment: @FonR I wouldn't use "something like" if I knew what I was doing :] I am mostly guessing and assuming when I try to answer. `.UsedRange` also includes blank formatted cells or formulas, so it is not always the best option but usually is good enough for me. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/918/methods-for-finding-the-last-used-row-or-column-in-a-worksheet